# about editing only 1 row in a table

Tags: php, mysql

How to edit a row in mysql using php.
I have a table , i will fetch it into php page to display the table in html format and at the end i have a edit button when i click edit button then the row should be editable and i can enter  new values and that should update in the same table row.. after c licking edit button the button should change to submit/update...

[image: This is the image of the table, the values here are in text boxes but readonly when the user clicks first edit the first row should be writable and the entered values should store]

Comment: What have you tried? What is the specific problem? The mysql part or the PHP part?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple method:

**HTML** for each EDIT link add the `id` of the row:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=4">EDIT</a>
```

**edit.php** :

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
   echo "start editing the row that have id".$id;
}
```

Comment: i dont want it to go for other page.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the basic actions, which falls into the category of CRUD functions. Here are the few steps you need to know to get you started.

- Pass a unique id of the record a edit page or class.
- You may attach the `id`, to the edit link of each page.
- This page will use this `id` and fetch the record from the database
- The details will be used to fill up of a form, from which the user will update the records.
- The form will also keep the record of the `id` in most probably a hidden element.
- Next, when this edit form is submitted, a processing will create a `UPDATE` query based on the data and execute them.

Comment: The example of the second step, is in the answer given by mgraph.

Comment: i dont want it to go for other page. the table row itself be writable and submitable

Answer (score 0):

The **Jquery Editable Data Tables** plugin could be the best solution you need. See code google for documentation and implementation here:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/

**Note:** Doing basic CRUP is completely time-consuming, both in the back-end and front-end, and other people  usually solved this predicament a long time ago, you just need to HUG their solutions, and customize them to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

But always when you asked help of other tell what you have tried..

This is just rough graph:-

```
$data = $_REQUEST;

if((isset($data['user_ids'])) && (count($data['user_ids']) == 1)){

 $id =$data['user_ids'][0];
    $sql= "UPDATE no_service SET `Status` = '$data[status_select_update]' WHERE id = $id ";

}elseif ((isset($data['user_ids'])) && (count($data['user_ids']) > 1)) {

    $ids = implode(",",$data['user_ids']);
    $sql= "UPDATE no_service SET `Status` = '$data[status_select_update]' WHERE id IN($ids)";

}else{
}
```

Edit is totally based on your id.. what you are passing.. Based on that id it will updated your records in Mysql..

I hope it will help..